# Is there a shorter version for this code?

Tags: java, android

is there a shorter version for this? can you explain why you consider it as a shorter/better version?

```
switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonUP:
                moveOBJECT.setY((moveOBJECT.getY() >= 0) ? moveOBJECT.getY() - 15 : moveOBJECT.getY());
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDOWN:
                moveOBJECT.setY((moveOBJECT.getY() + moveOBJECT.getHeight() < img.getHeight()) ? moveOBJECT.getY() + 15 : moveOBJECT.getY());
                break;
            case R.id.buttonLEFT:
                moveOBJECT.setX((moveOBJECT.getX() >= 0) ? moveOBJECT.getX() - 15 : moveOBJECT.getX());
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRIGHT:
                moveOBJECT.setX((moveOBJECT.getX() + moveOBJECT.getWidth() < img.getWidth()) ? moveOBJECT.getX() + 15 : moveOBJECT.getX());
                break;
        }
```

Comment: this is good. no need to short

Comment: @Divyesh someone told me that I can do this on one line, I mean I just want to know how it is done, and what method or concept will i use.

Comment: `getx , y` are redundant

Comment: @PavneetSingh, yes thats what my friend told me, but i have no idea how to code it non redundant. can you explain it to me?

Comment: i don't know the type of x,y but  for e.g do this at the top  your `type x=moveOBJECT.getX();` and  replace `moveOBJECT.getX()` with `x` in your `switch` and do the same for `y`

Comment: @PavneetSingh well now it looks shorter. but i feel like there is a way to do all 4 cases in one method/function

Comment: Major Bug: What happens if on entry to this code section the value of `x` or `y` is `>0` but `<15` and the event is (respectively) `buttonLEFT` or `buttonUp`?  Ditto for `RIGHT` and `DOWN` when less than 15 pixels from the edge.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, i noticed that, but dont worry about that, im working on it already. more importantly i wanna know how to make this in a one liner code. but thanks for noticing

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Answer (score 1):

Without refactoring the code I don't think there is a way to shorten it.

Maybe what would be better is to pass the getId() call into a moveObject.move( v.getId() ) and let the moveObject class handle the movement.

```
....... somewhere on your code
moveOBJECT.move( v.getId() );
.......

class MoveOBJECT extends view {
    public void move( enum buttonPressed key) {
        switch (key) {
                case R.id.buttonUP:
                    Y = Y >= 0 ? Y - 15 : Y;
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonDOWN:
                    Y = Y + height < img.getHeight() ? Y + 15 : Y;
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonLEFT:
                    X = X >= 0 ? X - 15 : X;
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonRIGHT:
                    X = X + width < img.getWidth() ? X + 15 : X;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you mean i create new class and let it handle the movement?
oh, btw moveOBJECT is a view not a class. sorry about the bad variable naming.

Comment: Ok I hadn't realised that. Maybe extending the view class and add a move method to it which you pass the getId into it. This approach won't shorten the code you are going to be moving it somewhere else but then you won't need the moveOBJECT.getX instead it will be X because you are already inside the class instance they are a member of

Comment: If you are doing lots of get/set requests on an object like you are doing here  it is always a design 'smell' and that the code should be moved into that class.

Comment: okay. well what i want to do is combine Up down left right in a single function. i mean dynamically. so i would call one function and i would just pass the parameters.

Comment: Im not quite sure by what you mean dynamically. I have edited my answer with a code examle of what I meant to see if that helps

Comment: what i mean is for code reusability. one dynamic function/method where i can just pass the values in the parameters. example: method(btnup)